# ByteBuffer mock allows all calls but I didn't set JMOCK to alow it

Tags: java, mocking, jmock

I have an issue with JMOCK 2.6 and JUINT4 when mocking ByteBuffer

```
@RunWith(JUnit4.class)
public class Test {

    @Rule
    public JUnitRuleMockery context = new JUnitRuleMockery() {
        {
            setImposteriser(ClassImposteriser.INSTANCE);
        }
    };

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
    }

    @org.junit.Test
    public void testMockByteBuffer() {
        final java.nio.ByteBuffer byteBufferMock = context.mock(java.nio.ByteBuffer.class);
        byteBufferMock.remaining();
    }

}
```

I expected the test to fail, but it passes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just realized I can't mock final methods.
java.nio.ByteBuffer.remaining() declared as  final.

from:
http://jmock.org/mocking-classes.html

> If you want to mock final classes or final methods, the JDave library includes an unfinalizer >Instrumentation agent that can unfinalise classes before they are loaded by the JVM. They can then be >mocked by the ClassImposteriser.